# GraphQL mutator with required args

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I am writing a mutation for a GraphQL schema:

```
const Schema = new GraphQLSchema({
  mutation: new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Mutation',
    fields: () => ({
      person: {
        type: GraphQLString,
        args: {
          name: {type: GraphQLString},
          school: {type: GraphQLString},
        },
        resolve: mutatePerson,
      },
    }),
  }),
});
```

I want to ensure that `mutatePerson` will only work if both `name` and `school` arguments are present. How can I check that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `GraphQLNonNull` type wrapper is used to specify both fields and arguments as non-null. For fields, that means the value of the field in the query results cannot be null. For arguments, that means that the argument cannot be left out or have a value of null. So your code just needs to look more like this:

```
args: {
  name: {
    type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString),
  },
  school: {
    type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString),
  },
},
```

Comment: When I do this and then leave out the argument `name` I get an exception `Field "person" argument "name" of type "String!" is required but not provided`

Comment: Is that not the behavior you were trying to implement? If not, please clarify in your question what exact behavior you're trying to implement

Comment: I'd like an error response sent to the client, not just an error printed out to the console on the server side

Comment: That error will be returned to the client as part of the `errors` array in the response.  If you're not seeing that, we'd need to see more of your server-side code and know what kind of response the client *is* receiving when making the request

Comment: Ah, it was a problem with my error handling. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

it is better to do it as follow (in the model) if you want to reject empty Strings like "", it is different from Null, this way you can reject both Null and empty "".

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const buinessSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  address: { type: String, required: true },
  phone: { type: String, required: true },
  email: { type: String, required: true },
  website: { type: String, required: true },
  currency: { type: String, required: true },
  aboutus: { type: String, required: true },
  terms: String,
  slogan: String,
  logo: { type: String, required: true }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Buiness", buinessSchema);
```